# remove time from POSIXct Date

Tags: r

I have convert my date from chr to POSIXCT using formula below.

```
crime2$Date = parse_date_time(crime2$Date, orders = c('dmy_HM'),tz="UTC")
```

so my date actually now in this format.

```
> head(crime2$Date, 10)
 [1] "2015-03-18 19:44:00 UTC" "2015-03-18 22:45:00 UTC"
 [3] "2015-03-18 22:30:00 UTC" "2015-03-18 22:00:00 UTC"
 [5] "2015-03-18 23:00:00 UTC" "2015-03-18 21:35:00 UTC"
 [7] "2015-03-18 22:50:00 UTC" "2015-03-18 23:40:00 UTC"
 [9] "2015-03-18 23:30:00 UTC" "2015-03-18 22:45:00 UTC"
```

However, if i want to remove the time and keep the date only, what can i do about this?

Example, they will look like this

```
" 2015-03-18 " "2015-03-18 "
```

Comment: Actually you can't since it's the defined `POSIX` format. You could do `as.Date(crime2$Date)` to get `Date` format.

Comment: i see...so that's what the issue is, need to redo the whole thing then, thanks!